# Prolog- How to append elements to end of list

Tags: prolog

I am trying to write a function where, given a list of variables and lists, will return the first list of all uninterrupted variables, like this:
this value [_1, _2, _3, _4, [1, 3], _5, _6] would return [_1, _2, _3, _4]

The code is returning false, I'm guessing the append function is comparing the Esp list with the concatenation of [P], and Esp1, how do I fix this?
I want Esp to be [P, Esp1].

My code:

```
espaco_aux([P|R],Esp,Esp1) :-
   var(P), espaco_aux(R, _, Esp1), append([P],Esp,Esp1).
```

[My code as an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mOvN.png)

Comment: Can't run your image in my Prolog interpreter. must have ASCII code. [mcve] please.

Answer (score 0):

First, since you want Esp to be the concatenation of P and Esp1, you need `concat([P],Esp1,Esp)`. Second, you need a termination case, giving you:

```
espaco_aux([P|R],Esp) :-
   var(P), !, espaco_aux(R, Esp1), append([P],Esp1,Esp).

espaco_aux(_,[]).
```

But you can simplify it further, by replacing the append with pattern matching:

```
espaco_aux([P|R],[P|Esp1]) :-
   var(P), !, espaco_aux(R, Esp1).

espaco_aux(_,[]).
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I got it to work eventually and forgot to check stack overflow but yeah I ended up doing something similar to your solution.

Comment: I you vote up or accept it that helps :) or you can write your own version of an answer and accept that